# InactiveScopeException when using doctrine:fixtures:load

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, scope, request, fixtures

I have a event listener registered as follow :

```
evo_app.listener:
    class: %evo_app.listener.class%
    arguments:  [@service_container, @event_dispatcher]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

and the service :

```
<?php

namespace Evo\AppBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Contact;
use Evo\UserBundle\Entity\Customer;
use Evo\UserBundle\EvoUserEvents;
use Evo\UserBundle\Event\CustomerEvent;

class Listener
{
    /**
     *
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher
     */
    protected $eventDispatcher;

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param Container $container
     * @param EventDispatcher $eventDispatcher
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container, EventDispatcher $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    /**
     * prePersist
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        // Contact entity
        if ($entity instanceof Contact) {
            if (null === $entity->getType()) {
                $entity->setType($em->getRepository('EvoBackendBundle:ContactType')->find(2));
            }
        }

        // Customer entity
        if ($entity instanceof Customer) {
            $request = $this->container->get('request');
            $routeName = $request->getRequestUri();

            // On appel l'event d'insert du customer
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(EvoUserEvents::PRE_CUSTOMER_INSERTED, $event = new CustomerEvent($entity, $routeName));
        }
    }

    /**
     * postPersist
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // Customer entity
        if ($entity instanceof Customer) {
            $request = $this->container->get('request');
            $routeName = $request->getRequestUri();

            // On appel l'event d'insert du customer
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(EvoUserEvents::POST_CUSTOMER_INSERTED, $event = new CustomerEvent($entity, $routeName));
        }
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // Customer entity
        if ($entity instanceof Customer) {
            $request = $this->container->get('request');
            $routeName = $request->getRequestUri();

            // On appel l'event d'insert du customer
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(EvoUserEvents::PRE_CUSTOMER_UPDATED, $event = new CustomerEvent($entity, $routeName, $args));
        }
    }
}
```

When browsing the site, everything is ok. But when I try to load fixtures, especially a "Customer" fixture, which create and persist a new Customer entity, I got the following error in the CLI :

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException]
  You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").

I guess it's because of line 58 of the service : `$request = $this->container->get('request');` because CLI mode cannot access the request.

How can I make this service works for both browser and CLI ?